# How to get list friend twitter using FHSTwitterEngine?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, twitter

i'm a new IOS dev. 
i'm trying to use `FHSTwitterEngine` to get list friend follower. I can get followerID, but i cant get name,language...
i read old post about get friend/list twitter in this page, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show , users/lookup. 
But it could not help me. 
Does anyone have a tutorial or example use `FHSTwitterEngine` to get friend/list twitter?
P/S:sorry about my english.

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution. Did you find anything?